# Filtering in the backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection in the below format, comma separated values in one of the attributes

```
var my_collection = {
    {
       "name" : "test1",
        "field" : "a,b,c"      
    },

    {
       "name" : "test2",
        "field" : "a,c"      
    },

};
```

I wanted to filter the attribute 'field' of value 'a' from the above collection, so that it should return test1 and test2.

I tried using `var filtered = my_collection .where({field: 'a'});` this will do the exact match of "field:a" only.

Any solution to filter the test1 and test2 when the user given the value "field:a"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider using an array instead of a comma separated value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) -- it's like _.where, except lets you specify a function as the predicate.  Then use `split` along with `indexOf` to check if "field" contains your item:

```
my_collection.filter(function(x) { 
    return x.field && x.field.split(',').indexOf("a") != -1; 
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54zRN/1/)